# From where does Amazon Rekognition get its face images database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I know this doesn't perfectly fit into a technical question, but out of curiosity, where does Amazon Rekognition get its faces from? Any particular database which we can directly use instead of using Rekognition?

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, *you* supply the faces.

In special cases, such as [celebrities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/celebrities.html), Amazon sources the faces from public images, most likely.

Note that a Rekognition face collection doesn't actually contain *any* images of faces. It contains vectors of features derived from images of faces.